# Show All Configurable Product Attributes without Selection

Tags: css, magento, attributes

I have products on my site with two configurable attributes: color & size. Right now, with default magento settings/coding the second attribute is hidden until the first is selected.

Example 1: [Breaker Rashguard](https://tugasunwear.com/breaker-rashguard-shark)

I would like to show all options for both attributes without any selection being made, or by having a default selection for color on each product (by default, first option in list). I've seen this done on Gap's website:

Example 2: [Heathered Oxford Shirt](http://www.gap.com/browse/product.do?cid=1013289&vid=1&pid=989082002)

I am using Amasty's Color Swatches Pro extension to replace the drop down selectors with color swatches. From what they can tell me, their extension does not rule this option and has no effect on any changes made to core code.

Can someone explain how to show my products like example 2?

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between **attribute** and super **attribute**.

**Attribute** - You create the custom product options.

**Super Attribute** - The system automatically creates when if use one cofigurado product

In your case is super attribute that is enabled if the former is chosen, i believe that by css you will not get a solution, will have to analyze the source code.

When the first option is selected, it enables the second option if it has stock with those attributes.

Maybe if you do not use stock quantity with the configured products should display without disabling.